# Is there any such thing as gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, equivalence-principle

So I was seeing this documentary and ended up knowing that there is no such thing as gravity. It said that we are not being pulled by Earth but being pushed by the space time curvature acc. to general theory of relativity.
I am really confused right now.

Are we being pulled by Earth or being pushed towards Earth?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61899/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116608/ and possible http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57228/

Comment: This question is too vague as it stands. What documentary? Best advice: Switch to a different channel, switch to anything else when you see a documentary filled with physics woo. Of course there's such a thing as gravity.

Comment: But doesnt the general theory of relativity say that we are being pushed towards earth by the space time curvature?