# What exerts force, the electric field of a charged body or the body itself?

Tags: forces, electric-fields

When another charged body is placed in the electric field of a charged body, the field exerts a force of attraction or repulsion or the body itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplistically, we can say that it is the field that exerts the force. Say the Sun disappears in an instant, it is known popularly that the earth should revolve around the position where the Sun existed for 8 minutes, the time taken for the information of Sun's disappearance to reach earth. So it is not the body itself (Sun) that is exerting the force, it is the field that does it.

Non-contact forces are modelled at fundamental levels with more advanced concepts like quantum mechanics and force mediators. [How do non-contact forces work ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267959/how-do-non-contact-forces-work)