# What causes Gravitation?

Tags: gravity

chemical reactions occur spontaneously because they increase the entropy of the universe.
but why does gravitation occur spontaneously? if anything, gravitation decreases the entropy of the universe.

Comment: What you are hoping is the concept of [entropic force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_force#:~:text=In%20physics%2C%20an%20entropic%20force,force%20on%20the%20atomic%20scale.) but that is not yet accepted theory in physics. We consider gravitation as an effect of space-time curvature in 4 dimensions.

Comment: Thermodynamics might be incorporated in General Relativity, the theory of gravitation. But that is not fully achieved yet.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116608/2451 and links therein.