# Origin of gravitational force

Tags: gravity

1. My teacher asked me a question to tell what the origin of gravitation or gravitational force was. In other words, what causes gravitational forces?

I considered some theories that it may be due to the mass of bodies. I also considered the gravitational waves interaction between two bodies which could be a cause of this force. I also considered the theory that suggests that all bodies are continuously emmiting gravitons. But I couldn't find the actual answer.

2. And why gravitational force always attractive?

Comment: Your question may be closed as too broad a topic for discussion.

Comment: The first subquestion (v2) is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81220/2451. The second subquestion (v2) is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/2451. See also links therein.

Comment: Feynman had a great discussion of this general topic in his lectures.  http://www.cornell.edu/video/richard-feynman-messenger-lecture-1-law-of-gravitation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we have theories about why gravity exists/how it works?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81220/)