# What causes the gravitational force to exist between two (uncharged) masses?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

We already know that electrical forces exist between two charged particles: likes repel and opposites attract. However, there always exists a gravitational force between two masses, even when they are not charged. They are directly propotional to the masses of the objects, and inversely propotional to the square of distance between them. But what is the physical reason behind the existence of this gravitational force, whose equation was discovered by Newton?

Comment: Electrical forces exist due to electric charge $q$. Gravitational forces exist due to gravitational charge, which is defined to be the mass $m$ of the object.

Comment: Why do you happen to easily accept the electrical force, but not the gravitational force?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81220/2451